# Duplicates using python, if any create a new column when there's a match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently trying to conduct an analysis where people might be doing something to avoid the system. So, I created a new field inside my dataFrame where I appended the Issue Date and the Name of the potential offender. What I want is: if any of the rows have the same Audit ID, say yes, if not, NaN.

So for example, I have:

```
Offender Name  Issue Date  Audit ID
Joe            12/02/2020  Joe-12/02/20
Nic            20/02/2020  Nic-20/02/20
Mat            01/02/2020  Mat-01/02/20
Joe            12/02/2020  Joe-12/02/20
```

And I want something like:

```
Offender Name  Issue Date  Audit ID        Matches
Joe            12/02/2020  Joe-12/02/20    Yes
Nic            20/02/2020  Nic-20/02/20    No
Mat            01/02/2020  Mat-01/02/20    No 
Joe            12/02/2020  Joe-12/02/20    Yes
```

I'd appreciate any insights anyone can give me

Comment: "No" is not the same as "NaN" and it appears that you haven't actually attempted this yourself. What are you stuck on?

Comment: My bad I about 'No' and 'NaN'.. And actually yes I have been trying to find a way, I originally did a groupby and count the matches and then merge the results with my current dataframe. However I'm looking for a more efficient approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark duplicates with 'Yes' and 'No'

```
df['Matches'] = df.duplicated('Audit ID', keep=False).map({True: 'Yes',False: 'No'})
df
```

Out:

```
  Offender Name  Issue Date      Audit ID Matches
0           Joe  12/02/2020  Joe-12/02/20     Yes
1           Nic  20/02/2020  Nic-20/02/20      No
2           Mat  01/02/2020  Mat-01/02/20      No
3           Joe  12/02/2020  Joe-12/02/20     Yes
```

---

The column `Audit ID` is redundant. You have the same informations in your dataframe already

```
df['Matches'] = df.duplicated(['Offender Name','Issue Date'], keep=False).map({True: 'Yes',False: 'No'})
df
```

Out:

```
  Offender Name  Issue Date      Audit ID Matches
0           Joe  12/02/2020  Joe-12/02/20     Yes
1           Nic  20/02/2020  Nic-20/02/20      No
2           Mat  01/02/2020  Mat-01/02/20      No
3           Joe  12/02/2020  Joe-12/02/20     Yes
```

Comment: Awesome! And you are right about the redundant column, appreciate this! Thank you